# GPIO Controlling Webpage

Tags: gpio, networking, web-server

Hi Guys this may seem a bit off topic.

Is there a web page that exists which displays the Rpi GPIO pins and allows to control them? Using the web page. This web page should display the GPIO pinout and the output of the GPIO should be controlled and with a simple click, it can turn on a GPIO pin and off. I am currently building a platform for beginners as a project this is aimed at people with little programming knowledge and would like to see how the GPIO pins work. This will be hosted locally. I would like to know if such a thing exists. Also if there are certain things i should be aware of.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are a few out there. The one that I like is by NeonHorizon (Daniel Bull) and is called BerryIO. You can [download it from GitHub](https://github.com/NeonHorizon/berryio).

[image: BerryIO user interface]